# Bootstrap Hover Pop ups for hyperlink buttons

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

First post on here so if this isn't in the right spot or theres any issues just let me know!

I am using bootstrap to make a main page of a SharePoint 2013 page. I have a couple of buttons which are used to navigate to different pages.

I would like to add a Hover feature to the so that when 'Hovered over' a text box, image, etc appears but when clicked the user is taken to the pre determined location.

So far I am using:

```
<nav>
      <ul class="nav nav-justified">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="URL">Business Architecture</a></li>
        <li><a href="URL">Operations</a></li>
        <li><a href="URL">Chnage Management</a></li>
        <li><a href="URL">Assist</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Please note I haven't touched the 'Home' Button as yet, only the others. I also have hover colour turned on via:

```
<STYLE type=text/css>
A:link { COLOR: Grey/*The color of the link*/}
A:visited { COLOR: #Grey/*The color of the visited link*/}
A:hover { COLOR: Black /*The color of the mouseover or 'hover' link*/}
BODY { COLOR: #454545/*The color of all the other text within the body of the page*/}
</STYLE>
```

The rest is built primarily from bootstrap existing templates as im still new to this and only getting used to HTML/CSS.

thanks
Matt

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the built in **Popover JS** feature. Refer to the Bootstrap 3 [Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers) for all the available options. See working example Snippet.

```js
var originalLeave = $.fn.popover.Constructor.prototype.leave;
$.fn.popover.Constructor.prototype.leave = function(obj) {
  var self = obj instanceof this.constructor ? obj : $(obj.currentTarget)[this.type](this.getDelegateOptions()).data('bs.' + this.type);
  var container, timeout;

  originalLeave.call(this, obj);

  if (obj.currentTarget) {
    container = $(obj.currentTarget).siblings('.popover');
    timeout = self.timeout;
    container.one('mouseenter', function() {

      clearTimeout(timeout);

      container.one('mouseleave', function() {
        $.fn.popover.Constructor.prototype.leave.call(self, self);
      });
    });
  }
};


$('body').popover({
  selector: '[data-popover]',
  trigger: 'click hover',
  placement: 'auto',
  html: "true",
  delay: {
    show: 50,
    hide: 400
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  color: #454545;
  /*The color of all the other text within the body of the page*/
}
a:link {
  color: grey;
  /*The color of the link*/
}
a:visited {
  color: grey;
  /*The color of the visited link*/
}
a:hover {
  color: black;
  /*The color of the mouseover or 'hover' link*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav>
  <ul class="nav nav-justified">
    <li class="active"><a href="#" data-popover="true" title="Home" data-content="<a href='http://example.com'>Home</a>">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="URL" data-popover="true" title="Business Architecture" data-content="<a href='http://example.com'>Business Architecture</a>">Business Architecture</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="URL" data-popover="true" title="Operations" data-content="<a href='http://example.com'>Operations</a>">Operations</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="URL" data-popover="true" title="Change Management" data-content="<a href='http://example.com'>Change Management</a>">Change Management</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="URL" data-popover="true" title="Assist" data-content="<a href='http://example.com'>Assist</a>">Assist</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Hi Vanburenx. Just wondering where I would put the coding that you mentions at the Top? I have tried doing this but I only get a small non formatted popup that doesn't look very nice, so im guessing that coding is used to make it look nice but I cant seem to get it working.

Comment: This would generally be in a JS file with any other custom scripts you have: this may help https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/75863/add-javascript-to-every-page-in-sharepoint-2013

Comment: ok thanks, that helps but unfortunately makes it very difficult as we aren't allowed to modify the master pages for each site (perks of working for a company with 30k+ employees...)